ASM as a DSL of a HLL?
There used to be a lot of discussion as regards embedding DSLs (Domain Specific Languages) into high-level languages (HLLs). The only example, where this is possible, I know of, is c++ and I had something like this in mind:
auto vm("ADD A, B"_z80);
vm.A = vm.B = 1;
vm.run();
std::cout << vm.A << std::endl;

But does some DSL implementation like this already exist? Maybe it's not a good idea? The implementation would not necessarily need to have anything to do with Z80 emulation. Being able to play with something like this would be immensely fun.

While I have a hard time to see this as retro (nor a DSL at all), you might want to have a look at Omar's project, featured over at meta, which seems related.

Turbo Pascal and Turbo C have inline assembly, to mention something on-topic, as does gcc IIRC. There are probably plenty more. But embedding arbitrary DSL's, that's a wide and complicated field.

what I had in mind was a compile-time interpreter, that would instantiate a vm instance in the sense of generative programming (the asm would configure the vm instance, so the asm would run across all platforms that support the host language, c++ in this case).

@user1095108 with that use case you may have left the scope of RC.SE by far.

To start with, it might be helpful to keep in mind that the Z80 is not an all out symmetric CPU, and your example directly points at that, as there is no ADD A, B. All operations are implied with A, so only an ADD B exists.
This might close some of the ideas you had about this usage.
So keeping in mind that instruction are not really generic but special to function, the step to directly use assembler isn't as big as it seems.
For example creating that method using SDCC's Inline Asssembler:
unsigned char vm_func(unsigned char A, usigned char B)
{
    __asm
    ld  iy,#2    ; Return Address
    add iy,sp

    ld  a,(iy)   ; A
    ld  b,1(iy)  ; B

    ADD B        ;<- The code you want to test

    ld  l,a      ;return value

    ret
    __endasm;
}

(For more details see section 4.1.5 of the manual)
By packaging pro- and epilogue into C-macros one could use this almost the same way as your prototype suggests.

yeah, but you need to run a sdcc binary in an emulator (say, fuse), but you'd be able to compile my example on the host system and run it there. It's not a big deal, I know, but it makes the idea super-fun. You could be running your old routines on super-modern windoze, for example.

@user1095108 It sounds as if you're looking more for a separate emulator that's convenient to call from your language than an assembler embedded into another language. Perhaps something similar to my CPU simulators in Python that let me use pytest to call and test 8-bit assembly code (t8dev).

hmm, yes, very interesting :) I'll bookmark your project :)

@user1095108 as cjs mentioned, your idea seems more like a modern project, rather  inspired by classic tech than really using it. In that case, it might be way less work to simply write that kind of emulation you think of in form of above syntax than to adapt any existing tools. After all, instruction set of Z80 is rather small and easy to implement, so making it fit your HLL environment would be the major part anyway.

@Raffzahn I'll write it as soon as I can, but I don't think my question is off-topic. I never intended to implement a modern ASM and it would be a lot of work anyway, as you noted. My goal was to write routines on my desktop, test them, then copy/paste into source files, compile and run the resulting binaries under an emulator. I'll update my question once my work is complete.

@user1095108 That question is different enough that you should probably write a new one. And it really sounds as if what you want does not require and in fact has nothing at all to to do with DSLs, but is about testing assembly code fragments on a modern machine before running them on an old machine. (That is _exactly_what t8dev supports; see examples under src/ (fragments) and exe/ (programs assembled from those fragments) in my 8bdev repo.)

Yes, it's existed in various shapes and forms over the years. BBC Basic, for example, supports inline assembly. I believe that some Lisp systems on minicomputers did as well. It's an obvious enough idea that it's surely been implemented many, many times, even before C started doing it.
What you're asking seems rather vague and would perhaps benefit from a bit more focus.
Lisp Example
Here's an example of x86 assembler embedded in Common Lisp; this comes from the source code to CMU Common Lisp. This is what is called a deep embedding: there's not a separate parser for a separate assembly language (as there is in BBC BASIC), but the assembly syntax is Lisp syntax.
You can see a few examples of what a deep embedding like this does: the "labels" such as BIGNUM are Lisp symbols and work the same way, native Lisp is intermixed with assembly in this example, and the function produced, move-from-unsigned, can be used just like any other Lisp function. And you can of course use all the techniques you use on "regular" Lisp code, such as macros.
(define-assembly-routine
  (move-from-unsigned)
  ((:temp eax dword-reg eax-offset)
   (:temp ebx dword-reg ebx-offset)
   (:temp ecx dword-reg ecx-offset))

  (inst test eax #xe0000000)
  (inst jmp :nz bignum)
  ;; Fixnum
  (inst mov ebx eax)
  (inst shl ebx 2)
  (inst ret)

  BIGNUM
  ;;; Note: On the mips port space for a two word bignum is always
  ;;; allocated and the header size is set to either one or two words
  ;;; as appropriate. On the mips port this is faster, and smaller
  ;;; inline, but produces more garbage. The inline x86 version uses
  ;;; the same approach, but here we save garbage and allocate the
  ;;; smallest possible bignum.
  (inst jmp :ns one-word-bignum)
  (inst mov ebx eax)

  ;; Two word bignum
  (with-fixed-allocation (ebx ecx bignum-type (+ bignum-digits-offset 2))
    (storew eax ebx bignum-digits-offset other-pointer-type))
  (inst ret)
  
  ONE-WORD-BIGNUM
  (with-fixed-allocation (ebx ecx bignum-type (+ bignum-digits-offset 1))
    (storew eax ebx bignum-digits-offset other-pointer-type))
  (inst ret))

(I'm quite certain that there are much earlier examples of this technique; if anybody can find some from the '60s or '70s I'd appreciate a pointer!)
BBC BASIC Example
BBC BASIC uses a shallow embedding: there's a parser separate from the BASIC parser that's run on assembly language fragments. In the following example from World of Spectrum you can see a couple of the issues that this raises: you can't intermix BASIC in the assembly code, the labels in assembly are not known to BASIC, and you need to manually run the parser, sometimes more than once. (In this case, the FOR loop runs it twice so that on the second pass the assembler can resolve the forward reference; the OPT pass% tells the assembler to suppress unknown reference error that would otherwise appear on the first pass.)
        100 DIM code 100
        110 FOR pass%=0 TO 2 STEP 2
        120 P%=code
        130 [
        140 OPT pass%
        150 ld bc,13
        160 jr label
        170 ld bc,26
        180 .label
        190 ret
        200 ]
        210 NEXT pass%


Wow, lisp and asm :) What I had in mind was a compile-time interpreter that would instantiate a vm instance..

As a comment, since I never actually did it - I heard it from a friend. On the IBM/370 it seems that a Fortran common block was equivalent to a label. So, they created a common block, filled it with machine code, and then used goto to jump to the common block and execute the code (which, of course, required appropriate return handling). Since the common block was data, it could be changed during execution as well.

A minor correction - in the BBC BASIC assembler, labels are just BASIC variables. Thus, you can write OSWRCH=&FFEE in BASIC before the assembly runs, so that "call OSWRCH" works inside the assembly language block. And similarly (but less commonly used), if you have .function inside your assembly block, the BASIC variable "function" will be set to the PC at that label.
